# Why was Zsaji not given the knowledge of English?

Tags: marvel, secret-wars-1985

In Marvel's *Secret Wars*, the Beyonder had taken care that all the 'fighters' would have an environment suitable for them, meaning, Zsaji the Healer had been put there by him.

However, we understand that Zsaji does not speak English, How was that favourable? Was it a mistake on his part, or was that done on purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer to this question necessarily requires some speculation, since we don't know whether the placement of Zsaji's village on Battleworld was a conscious choice on the Beyonder's part, or whether it just happened to be pulled along for the ride when he constructed Battleworld from those planetary fragments he threw together.

Even if it was a conscious choice on his part, we can't be sure what the thought process behind that decision was. Captain Marvel (Monica Rambeau) assumed that the Beyonder wanted the alien villagers there as "innocent victims". For all we know, she could've been right about that, but then again, she could've just as easily been wrong. It's all guesswork.

[Marvel Super Heroes Secret Wars #4](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiJ7-mv1oHsAhWMasAKHf_uB4kQFjAAegQIBBAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmarvel.fandom.com%2Fwiki%2FMarvel_Super_Heroes_Secret_Wars_Vol_1_4&usg=AOvVaw1gseMh6YlEOj8m5w7iFFRh)

[image]

[image]

The main utility Zsaji offered to the Earthly combatants, though, was her power of healing. So if we assume, for the sake of argument, that the Beyonder consciously placed her on Battleworld for that specific reason, then she clearly served her purpose, despite her inability to speak English. It's not so much that it was *favourable* for her not to speak English, as it just *didn't matter* in terms of what she was there to do.

Answer (score 3):

Because a common spoken language wasn't really needed when you can use telepathy instead. With the assistance of some type of vaporous drug, Zsaji and Johnny Storm are able to communicate mind to mind:

[image]

[image]

...

[image]

The Beyonder apparently had calculated that this type of communication would be sufficient, and evidently that was correct. In fact it seemed that they are able to share information much more efficiently than using spoken language.

The story did only show one instance of this type of very "deep" communication but the alien residents were still able to interact with some of the other Earth heroes, namely Colossus. Body language and intuition proved to be sufficient in those other instances. Its clear however that in Colossus' relationship with Zsaji the lack of better communication was a major hinderance as shown through his unrequited love for her and her apparent obliviousness to it.

Comment: That ritual was only shown to be performed in that one scene though, and only between those two characters. For the most part, what little communication there was between the heroes and that species was entirely based on vocal intonations and body language.

Comment: @LogicDictates good thought. I've added something to address that. One could extrapolate that if the two cultures had interacted for longer the single or few instances of telepathic communication could have paved the way for more ordinary dialog.