# Is there a translation for the alien language used on Battleworld?

Tags: marvel, comics, secret-wars-1985

In *Marvel Super Heroes Secret Wars #4* ([Aug, 1984](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/10586/secret_wars_1984_4)) characters from an undetermined alien planet are introduced, and recur through the remaining issues. A portion of their world had been used to construct the Battleworld (where most of the story takes place) and so the 'heroes' come across them during the course of events. One of the aliens plays a significant role at several points of the remaining story.

Nearly all of their dialogue however is scripted in an alien language:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Other than one of the alien names being *transliterated* (i.e., just pronounced as closely as possible using English sounds), I don't think any of it was ever directly translated into English. The Earth characters mostly voice their impressions of what the aliens are saying, some of which was assisted by telepathy.

Was this culture, language or script ever identified in the Marvel Universe? Has it been or is it possible to translate it?

Comment: Huh, never realised Captain Kirk was in Secret Wars too.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite - Funny you should say that, since [the Human Torch used the term "Captain-Kirking"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROVda.jpg) as an apparent reference to kissing alien women.

Comment: @LogicDictates: ah! I did [read the series a few years back](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66058/how-did-secret-wars-fit-into-regular-comics-continuity), so I've probably subconsciously stolen the reference there.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite - Those panels in my previous comment were from _[Deadpool's Secret Secret Wars #3](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Deadpool%27s_Secret_Secret_Wars_Vol_1_3)_, rather than the original _[Marvel Super Heroes Secret Wars](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Super_Heroes_Secret_Wars_Vol_1)_ series, so it may be a genuine coincidence, unless you read both stories.

Comment: @LogicDictates Ahhhh, yeah I haven't read the Deadpool one. Typical Deadpool, always subconsciously stealing my references.

Answer (score 5):

### Pretty sure the answer to this question is "no".

Very little seems to have been revealed about that species, their culture, or their language.
Going by [Zsaji's](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Zsaji_(Earth-616))  bio in *[Secret Wars: Official Guide to the Marvel Multiverse](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Secret_Wars:_Official_Guide_to_the_Marvel_Multiverse_Vol_1_1)*, neither her species nor her homeworld even have established names as yet.

[image]

Also, the [Marvel Database](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Marvel_Database) lists Zsaji as having a total of just [16 appearances](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Zsaji_(Earth-616)/Appearances), and having looked through them, I've found no serious translation of (or even a name for) that particular language. I say "no serious translation", because there were humorous captions in *[Deadpool's Secret Secret Wars #3](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Deadpool%27s_Secret_Secret_Wars_Vol_1_3)* and *[Howard the Duck Vol 5 #4](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Howard_the_Duck_Vol_5_4)* implying that a couple of words in the alien language translated into English as profanities.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Linking [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/237317/why-was-zsaji-not-given-the-knowledge-of-english), as it's tangentially related.